# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException while deploy .ear

Tags: java, web-services, ant, ejb, weblogic12c

```
<Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101371> <There was a failure when processing annotations for application \beadep\OLD_INTRANET_1\xxxx.war. Ensure that the annotations are valid. The error is 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.getEnvironmentType(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:1394)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.addWebServiceRef(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:354)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.processMethod(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:192)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.J2eeAnnotationProcessor.processMethod(J2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:56)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.processMethods(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:180)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Any solution to this long existing issue in new weblogic server

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2553488_1.html

You need access to Oracle Support for it.